# Google icons in KML does not match

Tags: google-maps, kml

I would like to use some nice icons I found on this page http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html.
I choose this icon http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon22.png 
but when I use it in a kml file, and display this KML in Google maps (or Google Earth), it appears as a double green triangle.

And this happens with many of the icons on that page.
What can I do ?

Here is a sample KML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns = 'http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2' >
<Document>
<Style id='scuola'>
<IconStyle>
<Icon>
<href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon22.png</href>
</Icon>
</IconStyle>
</Style>
<Placemark>
<name>L08940P06194</name>
<description><![CDATA[Point: L08940P06194 School<br>]]></description>
<styleUrl>#scuola</styleUrl>
<Point>
<coordinates>-72.3553467, 18.5366992, 0 </coordinates>
</Point>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

thanks
David Remotti

Comment: I see the same thing (compare the icon rendered by geoxml3 with the one from KmlLayer): http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_KML_Icon22.kml

Comment: thx this way is perfect. But how can I implement it in my application ? I'm writing the kml from PHP ...

Answer (score 2):

Under the covers Google Earth/Google Maps is remapping certain icon URLs such http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon22.png

If you choose the icons with the URL prefix: *http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal{2,3,4,5}*
then you will notice it being remapped to a "standard" icon with the URL prefix of *http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes*/.

**This is an undocumented feature of Google Earth and Google Maps.**

This "feature" is described in the [notes section](http://kml4earth.appspot.com/icons.html#notes) on the web site you mention in your question.

This particular mapping of icons is a little strange but most of the icon remapping seems somewhat reasonable:
[image: global icon] => [image: mountain icon]

Original URL: http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal3/icon22.png 
Mapped Icon: http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/mountains.png

Here's another mapping that is more intuitive:

[image: forest/park icon] => [image: park icon]

Original URL: http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/pal2/icon12.png
Mapped Icon: http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/parks.png

You can either:

1. Let Google Earth/Google Map remap the icon and live with it or
2. Make a copy of the original icon (e.g., save in Google Drive, etc.) and use the new URL (as a custom icon) in your KML to display it as-is.